# Removing element from ArrayList using Iterator

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

I have removed elements from Arraylist using iterator. But after removing size is not reduced and values remains same in Arraylist. I have used ArrayList as a class level variable. Doesn't  know why it is not working. 
Below is my code,

```
public class MyClass{
private ArrayList<String> valueArrayList;
Iterator itr = valueArrayList.iterator();
                while (itr.hasNext())
                    if (validateFile((String) itr.next())) {

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "values removed");

                    } else
                        itr.remove();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `itr.remove()` in else case when validation log displayed in if condition (I.e. "values removed").

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede I have method for checking whether a file exist or not. So I am passing a string to it. If file path exist,then it will return true else false. If file doesn't exist, then I want to remove it from the list

Comment: @Jeel Vankhede I am using the ArrayList in some other place in the class. But after removing it is not updating my Arraylist.

Comment: try to put the log and check that else block getting reached?

Comment: Point is.. you're getting log ''values removed" when you're having true flag indicating file exists. So that log is generating ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's should be

```
Iterator<String> itr = valueArrayList.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    // If file doesn't exist
    if (!validateFile(itr.next())) {
        itr.remove(); // delete from list
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "values removed");
    }
}
```